# Rails 3 - string in URL - how to get it and what about routing

Tags: string, ruby-on-rails-3, url, controller, url-routing

I am newbie in RoR and a few past days I am struggling with strings in URL. I have some items in database and these items I would like to insert them to URL. For example, my web:

> www.web.com

Items in database:

> items1
>   items2
>   items3

I am thinking, how to edit **routes.rb** and my controller for following the shape of URL:

> www.myweb.com/items1

Had someone similar problem or have someone some hints, how to do? I would be very glad for any help. I have no idea how to do :/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Of course, I read it. My problem is, that I don't know, how to distinguish, if I have in URL only "web.com/my-item1" or "web.com/my-item2" and something with controller, as can be "web.com/person/index" or "web.com/info/about-us"

Answer (score 0):

The routes just have to be unique and the symbol is the value in the name value pair

```
    match '/item/:item_id' => 'controller#action'
    then get the item_id from params[:item_id]
```

The above is saying like example.com?item=1  using 1 as an example item_id
so say like

```
    match '/item/:category/:item_id' => 'controller#action'
```

example.com/item/foo_category/bar_item

```
    params[:category] = foo_category
    params[:item_id] = bar_item
```

but you couldn't have 2 routes like

```
   match '/item/:category' => 'controller#action'
   match '/item/:item_id' => 'controller#action'
```

because rails just sees it as /item/x and will probably match it with the first match in routes
Hope that helps.